# PhpStorm Library doesn't see library

Tags: github, phpstorm

```
<?php
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram as InstagramAlias;

$instagram = new InstagramAlias(array(
    'apiKey'      => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
    'apiSecret'   => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'apiCallback' => 'YOUR_APP_CALLBACK'
));

echo "<a href='{$instagram->getLoginUrl()}'>Login with Instagram</a>";
```

I added the library with composer when ı make

```
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram
```

it saw it but when i start to write the code it says there is no class named instagram

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram' not found in C:\Users\Zera\İnstagram\Insta.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Zera\İnstagram\Insta.php on line 4
```

Comment: 1) PhpStorm does not do any classes autoloading for you during code execution -- you need to handle that yourself (as your production code will be executed without PhpStorm anyway). 2) If you have installed that Instagram package via Composer -- do not forget to use Composer's autoloader -- it will handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Even though you add the library with "use ......" you need to make

```
require "the source path of the class"
```